# Show PHP Page while loading a function

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am developing a website, and I found a difficulties here. 
I have a function that run about 15 seconds.

```
<?php 
...
...
do_function($a); //This function run about 15 seconds. 
?>
```

and I have 'waiting_page.php' that I want to show without redirect while I wait this function. How to solve this problem?

Thanks,

Comment: AJAX. the typical attention span of an end user is less then 6 seconds.

Comment: Do you try to use AJAX? You load your page and after do a AJAX call to run your heavy function.

Comment: Have a look at the difference between server-side and client-side rendering. If a PHP function blocks the execution, it blocks the execution